# Help Identifying a Component (Varistor)

Tags: identification, components, varistor

I am trying to identify the component (I believe is a varistor) in the image below (is from a blender). In another piece of the epoxy I was able to read 14. Should I assume is a 14d241K? Tks!

Lino[image]

Comment: Consider this: I have one piece from a jigsaw, can I see the full picture?

Comment: The additional background is that the blender was connected to a 220V source (although is a 110V Blender) and the component was pretty much distroyed. Not possible to identify more details except the 14 (that cant be captured in a picture). Blender is a KitchenAid KSB1575WH.

Comment: i see  `/241K`, `/241R`, `/24TK` or `/24TR`

Comment: Is there a palaeontologist in the house?

Answer (score 0):

14d241K seems good for 110v and protect it against 220v.
But for urgent needs you can use any above your voltage or skip this component, if you already remember that 220v is bad for it.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This will help me choose a replacement.